# AddListener to Button in Prefab

Tags: unity, events, prefabs

I created a prefab called `MapNode` and have `MapGenerator` instantiate a bunch of them at runtime. I want to make the each instance of `MapNode` clickable and update some info on the UI.

`MapNode` looks like this:

```
MapNode(Script, Sprite Renderer, Canvas Renderer)
->Text(TMP)
->Button(Button, BoxCollider 2D)
```

In `Start()` of `MapGenerator`, I instantiate a bunch of `MapNode`s:

```
void Start()
{
    MapSystem mapSystem = mapSystemGO.GetComponent<MapSystem>();
    mapNodes = new MapNode[numMapNode];
    //generate mapNodes
    for(int x = 0; x < numMapNode; x++) {
        int width = (int)(mapWidth * 0.9);
        int height = (int)(mapHeight * 0.9);
        int posX = Random.Range(0, width);
        int posY = Random.Range(0, height);
        Vector3 position = new Vector3(posX, posY, -1);
        GameObject newMapNodeGO = Instantiate(mapNode, mapSystemGO.transform);
        mapNodes[x] = newMapNodeGO.GetComponent<MapNode>();
        mapSystem.RegisterNewMapNode(newMapNodeGO, x, "n_"+x, position);
        //passes the GameObject to MapSystem
    }
    //generate adjacencies
    // ...
}
```

After each clone is instantiated, it is passed to `RegisterNewMapNode()` in `MapSystem`, which looks like this:

```
public void RegisterNewMapNode(GameObject newMapNodeGO, int ID, string name, Vector3 position) {
        MapNode newMapNode = newMapNodeGO.GetComponent<MapNode>();
        newMapNode.mapNodeID = ID;
        newMapNode.mapNodeName = name;
        newMapNode.mapNodePosition = position;
        newMapNode.transform.position = position;
        Button button = newMapNodeGO.GetComponentInChildren<Button>();
        Debug.Log(button);
        Debug.Log("register "+newMapNode.mapNodeID+" "+newMapNode.mapNodeName);
        button.onClick.AddListener(delegate{ShowMapNodeInfo(newMapNode);});
        // calls ShowMapNodeInfo() to update UI
        mapNodes.Add(newMapNode);
}
```

`Debug.Log(button);` prints `Button (UnityEngine.UI.Button)` in the console, so it's probably found the button.
`ShowMapNodeInfo()` looks like this:

```
public void ShowMapNodeInfo(MapNode mapNode){
    Debug.Log("MapSystem: click "+mapNode.mapNodeID+" "+mapNode.mapNodeName);
    mapNodeInfo.showInfo(mapNode);
}
```

`mapNodeInfo.showInfo()` is meant to do the actual updating of the UI. However, the Debug statement in the first line is not getting triggered, which makes me think the function was not even called.
I think the problem is not that the click is not registered. I tried added `OnMouseDown()` to `MapNode` itself, and it worked fine.

```
void OnMouseDown() {
    Debug.Log("Clicked " + mapNodeID + " " + mapNodeName);
}
```

The Debug statement prints when I click on it.
However, I can't access an UI element in the scene using a function inside the prefab, so I have to add a listener outside, which isn't working.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you mean `newMapNode` for the parameter? Because the RegisterNewMapNode code does not include any `mapNode` variable.

Comment: Yes you're right, I changed that delegate call to another function while debugging and made a mistake when changing it back. It doesn't even compile with ```mapNode```.